# convert quote to order for guest users

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, sales-order, quote, sales-quote

Hi I am converting a quote to order programatically. 929 is a quote id of a guest user.When i am trying a actual customers quote id it is working fine.but for guest this is not working. giving error as

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getIncrementId() on a
>   non-object

here is my code

```
$quoteObj = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load(929); // Mage_Sales_Model_Quote
        $items = $quoteObj->getAllItems();  
         $quoteObj->reserveOrderId();

        //print_r($items);
$addressData = array(
        'firstname' => 'Test',
        'lastname' => 'Test',
        'street' => 'Sample Street 10',
        'city' => 'Somewhere',
        'postcode' => '123456',
        'telephone' => '123456',
        'country_id' => 'US',
        'region_id' => 12, // id from directory_country_region table
);

$billingAddress = $quoteObj->getBillingAddress()->addData($addressData);
$shippingAddress = $quoteObj->getShippingAddress()->addData($addressData);

$shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)->collectShippingRates()
                ->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate')
                ->setPaymentMethod('checkmo');

$quoteObj->getPayment()->importData(array('method' => 'checkmo'));

$quoteObj->collectTotals()->save();

$service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quoteObj);
$service->submitAll();
$order = $service->getOrder();

printf("Created order %s\n", $order->getIncrementId());
```

Please Help.

edit : This code is using rest api with put method.

```
public function checkout($postParams,$data){
        $response = array();
        $registryId = $postParams['registry_id'];
        $quoteId = $data['quote_id'];
        $quoteObj = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($quoteId);
        $quoteObj->reserveOrderId();
        $BillingData = array(
            'firstname' => $data['first_name'],
            'lastname' => $data['last_name'],
            'street' => $data['street_address'],
            'city' => $data['city'],
            'postcode' => $data['zipcode'],
            'telephone' => $data['phone'],
            'country_id' => $data['country'],
            'region_id' => $data['region'], 
            'quote_id' => $quoteId,
        );
    // addresses

        $billingAddress = $quoteObj->getBillingAddress()->addData($BillingData);
        $shippingAddress = $quoteObj->getShippingAddress()->addData($BillingData);
        $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)->collectShippingRates()
                ->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate')
                ->setPaymentMethod('checkmo');
        $quoteObj->getPayment()->importData(array('method' => 'checkmo'));
        $quoteObj->collectTotals();
        $service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quoteObj);
        $service->submitAll();
        $order = $service->getOrder();
        $IncrementId=$order->getIncrementId();
        $response['success'] = True;
        $response['message'] = "Order Placed Succesfully";
        $response['id']=$IncrementId;
        return $response;
    }
```

This is returning me the error for getting increent id and no order is placed.This is also adding a quote to quote item table with empty values.

Comment: hey @melvin i post answer. did you try my code??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following way:

```
$quoteObj = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load(706);
$items = $quoteObj->getAllItems();
$quoteObj->reserveOrderId();

//print_r($items);
$addressData = array(
    'firstname' => 'Test',
    'lastname' => 'Test',
    'street' => 'Sample Street 10',
    'city' => 'Somewhere',
    'postcode' => '123456',
    'telephone' => '123456',
    'country_id' => 'US',
    'region_id' => 12, // id from directory_country_region table
);

// addresses
$quoteShippingAddress = new Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address();
$quoteShippingAddress->setData($addressData);
$quoteBillingAddress = new Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address();
$quoteBillingAddress->setData($addressData);
$quoteObj->setShippingAddress($quoteShippingAddress);
$quoteObj->setBillingAddress($quoteBillingAddress);

$quoteObj->getShippingAddress()->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate');

$quoteObj->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
$quoteObj->getShippingAddress()->collectShippingRates();

$quoteObj->collectTotals();

// set payment method
$quotePaymentObj = $quoteObj->getPayment();
$quotePaymentObj->setMethod('checkmo');
$quoteObj->setPayment($quotePaymentObj);

$quoteObj->collectTotals()->save();

$service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quoteObj);
$service->submitAll();
$order = $service->getOrder();

printf("Created order %s\n", $order->getIncrementId());
```

Comment: it is just not working with quotes created through my api

Comment: ok now i figured out . the orders from my app is having storeid 0 ,when i change it manualy to 1 in db and try my code it works

Comment: $service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quoteObj);echo json_encode($service);exit; is giving me a empty stdClass Object ( )

Comment: I know it's late but can you put the code for login user

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working perfectly on my device. I checked for both logged in and guest users and I was successfully able to convert quote into the order on my device. There might be some value missing on your side.

As your code is fine that means there is problem in your objects like quoteObj.

Try to print data present in quoteObj by using getData() function like below -:

```
echo "<pre>";

print_r($quoteObj->getData());

echo "</pre>";
```

And check if there is something wrong.

Data in my quote object is as follows. You can compare your data with this data -:

Array

```
(
    [entity_id] => 7
    [store_id] => 1
    [created_at] => 2017-03-09 14:57:48
    [updated_at] => 2017-03-09 15:05:39
    [converted_at] => 
    [is_active] => 1
    [is_virtual] => 0
    [is_multi_shipping] => 0
    [items_count] => 1
    [items_qty] => 1
    [orig_order_id] => 0
    [store_to_base_rate] => 1
    [store_to_quote_rate] => 1
    [base_currency_code] => USD
    [store_currency_code] => USD
    [quote_currency_code] => USD
    [grand_total] => 105
    [base_grand_total] => 105
    [checkout_method] => 
    [customer_id] => 
    [customer_tax_class_id] => 3
    [customer_group_id] => 0
    [customer_email] => 
    [customer_prefix] => 
    [customer_firstname] => 
    [customer_middlename] => 
    [customer_lastname] => 
    [customer_suffix] => 
    [customer_dob] => 
    [customer_note] => 
    [customer_note_notify] => 1
    [customer_is_guest] => 0
    [remote_ip] => 127.0.0.1
    [applied_rule_ids] => 
    [reserved_order_id] => 100000005
    [password_hash] => 
    [coupon_code] => 
    [global_currency_code] => USD
    [base_to_global_rate] => 1
    [base_to_quote_rate] => 1
    [customer_taxvat] => 
    [customer_gender] => 
    [subtotal] => 100
    [base_subtotal] => 100
    [subtotal_with_discount] => 100
    [base_subtotal_with_discount] => 100
    [is_changed] => 1
    [trigger_recollect] => 0
    [ext_shipping_info] => 
    [gift_message_id] => 
    [is_persistent] => 0
    [virtual_items_qty] => 0
    [taxes_for_items] => Array
        (
        )

    [can_apply_msrp] => 
    [totals_collected_flag] => 1
)
```

Comment: i am getting only - Array ( [reserved_order_id] => 100000178 ) when store id is 0.when store id is 1 it is giving me the same like your array.

Comment: $service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quoteObj);echo json_encode($service);exit; is giving me a empty stdClass Object ( )

Answer (score 0):

I guess that  for Few values, ur order does not  created.

Make, Your ***quote  is active and Current Checkout module is guest***

```
$quoteObj->setIsActive(true)
->setCheckoutMethod(Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage::METHOD_GUEST)
->save()
```

After  adding shipping and billing address .. require to recalculated  total by

```
$quoteObj->collectTotals()->save();
```

Comment: $service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quoteObj);echo json_encode($service);exit; is giving me a empty stdClass Object ( )

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the checkout method as guest after setting the billing and shipping addresses. Please check the below code, it worked for me hopefully it will help in your case as well.

```
$quoteObj->setCheckoutMethod('guest')
        ->setCustomerId(null)
        ->setCustomerEmail($quoteObj->getBillingAddress()->getEmail())
        ->setCustomerIsGuest(true)
        ->setCustomerGroupId(Mage_Customer_Model_Group::NOT_LOGGED_IN_ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load('quote id');
$quote->getPayment()->importData(array('method' => 'cashondelivery'));
$quote->collectTotals()->save();
$service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quote);
$service->submitAll();
```

use this code. i use this code in my extension and its works fine

Comment: i am not able to get the increment id and and oreder is not getting placed for guest .$quoteObj->getPayment()->importData(array('method' => 'checkmo'));
  $quoteObj->collectTotals()->save();
  $service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quoteObj);
  $service->submitAll();
  $order = $service->getOrder();
  $IncrementId=$order->getIncrementId();  giving error  Call to a member function getIncrementId() on a non-object in

Comment: load quote by id . and print object data in log. did you find data ?? just check

Comment: can you check my updated qn

Comment: $service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quoteObj);echo json_encode($service);exit; is giving me a empty stdClass Object ( )